How to fix glossy texture when importing OBJ file?
I exported obj file from some object but when importing the all the texture on object are glossy.
I discovered that the problem is the color space for roughness, metallic, and normal are sRGB; they should be non-color.

The question is how to export the obj file was the correct color space.

That would depend on where your object is being imported from. There is no magic switch in the importer to change them automatically on import.

It doesn't matter if the node was set to a different color space on export, PNG and JPG files will always be imported as sRGB - because the files do not contain this color space information, this is only a Blender internal "work instruction" how the colors should be interpreted. Only the Node Wrangler's "Principled Texture Setup" (Ctrl+Shift+T) where you can import multiple images for color, roughness, normals etc. in one go automatically sets roughness etc. to Non-Color because it is implemented like that to switch them after import.
